# How to input commands to CTS-Tradefed?

Tags: android, python, shell, android-testing

I'm currently trying to automate few steps in android ICS CTS.

1. When we execute `./cts-tradefed` we get `cts-tf >` prompt.
2. then I am able to enter run `cts --plan CTS`
3. then exit command to exit from prompt.

Here I want to write all the above 3 steps in one shell script. But unable to do it with below script. Tried in many way but could not achieve it. Please help.

Want to execute:

**1.** `./cts-tradefed`

**2.** run `cts --plan CTS exit`

**3.** `./cts-tradefed`

**4.** `run cts --plan CTS`

**5.** `exit`

Help in any shell, python or perl languages appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Excerpt from *help* of CTS-tradefed (version 6.0_r0)

> exit: gracefully exit the cts console, waiting till all invocations are complete

We can leverage above argument to serve the purpose as follows:

```
echo exit | cts-tradefed <arguments to cts>
```

Comment: Used this small script to get a loop on bash shell. `while [ 1 ]; do echo exit | ./android-cts/tools/cts-tradefed run cts -c android.media.cts.DecoderTest -m testEOSBehaviorH264; sleep 1; done`

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure which version of CTS you are using, so I assume the version is `4.0.3_r3`.

You could execute the command `./cts-tradefed run cts --plan CTS` in one line.
However, the prompt still exist after finish the command.

According to [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24267),
I think there are no simple ways to solve it.

Therefore, I just apply the patch in the above link, and execute the following command:

> `echo | ./cts-tradefed run cts --plan CTS`

Answer (score 3):

With Android CTS 7.0, you can simply run this command line, it's most convenient for automation:
(Assume "cts-tradefed" is in your PATH.)

```
$ cts-tradefed run commandAndExit cts
```

Help from cts-tradefed:

```
r(?:un)? help:
    commandAndExit <config> [options] Run the specified command, and run 'exit -c' immediately afterward
    cmdfileAndExit <cmdfile.txt>      Run the specified commandfile, and run 'exit -c' immediately afterward
```